# How to run app that using armeabi native library with a emulated x86_64 device

Tags: android

I have a android app which using some native libraries, these libraries only have armeabi version.

Is that possible to test such a app with a emulated x86_64 device in android studio.

I see some people says intel has privided a bridge to convert arm instructions to x86. how can I enable it with those x86_64 images downloaded in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as native libraries are compiled into machine code and are loaded by Dalvik at run time, so you need a special java virtual machine which I do not think it exists